# How to join a new computer to domain?

Tags: login, domain, credentials

I'm trying to join a new computer to a domain. It asks me for the username and password, but when I enter them it says that the username and password are incorrect. But I know that they work properly on other computers.

What should I do?

Comment: What kind of domain? Home network? Corporate network? Are you an administrator? End user? Please add more details.

Comment: I you mean an AD domain, could it be that you made a typo when typing the password and the username is locked?

Comment: Details are important to getting a good answer. Please [edit] your question to include details like; what OS are you using, what type of domain, corporate or private network, how steps you are using to join the domain, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specify the domain in the username!

```
example.com\administrator
```